# What is the name of soundtrack in attack on titan season 3 part 2 trailer

Tags: music, attack-on-titan

I want to know the exactly sound track name in this trailer.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=a3mo2TZGXlM

All what I get is soundtracks name is like this not same one?

Answer (score 1):

The Song you are looking for is "ətˈæk 0N tάɪtn · MIKA KOBAYASHI · Hiroyuki Sawano"

https://youtu.be/zroFzv7sFis

https://genius.com/Hiroyuki-sawano-tk-0n-ttn-attack-on-titan-annotated

Comment: the video is not working, even if search with name I do not get the same soundtrack.
But thank you for helping

Comment: I listened to both the mentioned trailer and the song, it is the same. Maybe the video is not available in your country. I added the Genius Link to my comment.

Comment: Looks like the YouTube link is exclusive for Music Premium members now. Understandable since it's an official channel though.